# Parar escopo até mudar valor do input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um formulário, onde um captcha é validade via json:

```
$.getJSON('?verify&string=' + captcha, function( content ){
    if(content.comparation){
       $("#tokenCaptcha").val(content.token);
    }else{
        complete = false;
    }
});
```

Após algumas linhas, a função retorna true ou false para enviar o form ou não. O fato é que demora um tempão mudar o valor. Tanto que o form é enviado antes do valor ser modificado. Fiz um teste com um alert do valor, demorou torno de 1 segundo para dar o alert do token.

Comment: Como estás a iniciar esse `.getJSON`? e o que queres mudar? näo percebo o que queres fazer quando dizes "Parar escopo"...

Comment: Ele está fazendo uma requisição "assíncrona", obvio, mas a execução do escopo também esta assíncrona. Mesmo sem terminar a requisição `.getJSON` o escopo continua executando, e consequentemente o formulário é enviado sem mudar o parâmetro que eu quero (token)